# python subprocess env var in command

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to make use of an env variable in a python-called subprocess cmd.

I tried

```
myvar="myval"
echo $myvar
>>myval
```

python3:

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

env_vars = dict(os.environ)
task_cmd = "echo $myvar/stuff"
sp = subprocess.Popen(task_cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, env=env_vars)
sp.communicate()

out:
>> ('/stuff\n', '')
```

How can I make it that my output is `('myval/stuff\n', '')`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem.
You should `export` that variable for it to propagate to child processes.

Try

```
export myvar="myval"
```

Comment: I only need it in the command itself, I do not need it to be available to the child process. I was actually thinking the OS would do the substitution rather than python. I think your first answer was what I was looking for, as you are right, I can simply do the formatting in python.

Comment: There's no child process called `echo`... you're basically running the default shell, which is a child process of the python processes, and if you want it to be able to interpolate a variable you have to pass it on.

Comment: Ah, I understand! I did not realise the shell did not ahve the env variables avaiable if not passed